# php argument return a string with newline

Tags: php

i have a php script that takes in 1 argument for e.g. and i need to capture that argument and do a urlencode

Here is a sample code to show the issue

```
<?php

$input=$argv[1];
#$input="How are you.\nAre you free?";
echo "$input\n";
$escape_input = urlencode("$input");
echo "$escape_input";

?>
```

---

```
$ php test.php "How are you.\nAre you free?"
```

The output would be `How+are+you.%5CnAre+you+free%3F%` which is incorrect as the new line is not encoded properly.

But if you hardcode the same string in the code, it would work
Correct output: `How+are+you.%0AAre+you+free%3F%`

Comment: In your command, `\n` are 2 characters while in PHP code it is only 1.

Comment: How do I make it as 1, as i need to pass it from argument

Comment: *"which is incorrect as the new line is not encoded properly."* -- there is no newline character in your input string. `\n` is not a new line. It is the encoding of a new line character in strings in PHP source code. Pass a newline to your script and it will encode it properly.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the input of your code. As you have pointed out

```
echo urlencode("Hello\nWorld.");
```

prints `Hello%0AWorld.`, because `\n` is interpreted as the new line character if it is used inside the quotes in php, and thus `\n` is replaced with the new line character before it is passed to `urlencode`.

When you execute the code with `php test.php "How are you.\nAre you free?"` (lets say in bash), `$argv[1]` is a string with contains the backslash character followed by `n`. `urlencode` encodes the backslash and leaves `n` as is.

In order to run the code with a new line character, you should hit *enter* where the line break should be.

```
$ php test.php "How are you.
Are you free?"
```

Alternatively you can also manually interpret the sequence `\n` in the input and replace it with the new line character.

```
$input = str_replace("\\n", "\n", $argv[1]);
```

Please note that the first argument, the search pattern, is the string `\n` (backslash followed by `n`), and the second argument, the replace string, is the new line character.